# Return substring if contains character

Tags: python, string, substring

Given a string, "Bajsd 2-478 1278123" and string similar to that. Is there a method to pull only the substring which contains "-"?

So in this case, it would be, 2-478. The length of the entire string and the substring containing "-" can vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split the string and print the item if it contains "-"

```
print "".join([x for x in "Bajsd 2-478 1278123".split(" ") if "-" in x])
```

Answer (score 1):

With regular expressions:

```
import re
re.search("(\d-\d+)", "Bajsd 2-478 1278123").group()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `split` method along with testing if a substring contains "-":

```
>>> s = "Bajsd 2-478 1278123"
>>> splitted = s.split(" ")
>>> [substring for substring in splitted if "-" in substring][0]
"2-478"
```

The line `[substring for substring in splitted if "-" in substring][0]` means: "make a list out of the elements of `splitted` that contain `"-"`, and return the head of this list".